# How can I open the product in new tab?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

i want my product in new tab for user. if any one click on product the product display in new tab.

it's a woocommerce website which have multiple product but i want the product should be display in new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add target using jquery.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('li.product a.woocommerce-loop-product__link').attr('target' '_blank');
});
</script>
```

Above script will add "target=_blank" to all woocommerce product.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using JQuery, like

```
$('a').attr('target' '_blank');
```

This will select all the elements with `a` tag but you need to target the element according to your own DOM

Comment: You can also select a class for your product links
example:
$('.woocommerce-loop-product__link').attr('target' '_blank');